# Stand alone java classes unable to connect to database from tomcat7

Tags: postgresql, jsp, ubuntu, tomcat7, remote-access

I have a program that I am porting to a web interface.  It connects to my postgres database fine when I run standalone however when I install the jar in Tomcat and then import classes into my JSP the connection attempt just spins.

I am running Tomat7.  Is there something I have to add to tomcat in order for the connections to be allowed or do I have to modify my database manager to connect via tomcat?

I found this page but it's directed at connecting from the JSP.  All of my connections are done in classes in my jarfile.  There isn't any need for me to query from the JSP I have DAOs and DTOs already written to do that.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

I modified my connector classes to get connections from the connection pool.  Here is my connection manager (yes I know my error handling needs to be improved):

```
public DatabaseManager() {
    p.setUrl(url);java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@789caeb2 returned null for URL:postgres
    p.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    p.setUsername(user);
    p.setPassword(password);
    p.setJmxEnabled(true);
    p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
    p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
    p.setTestOnReturn(false);
    p.setValidationInterval(30000);
    p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
    p.setMaxActive(100);
    p.setInitialSize(10);
    p.setMaxWait(10000);
    p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
    p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
    p.setMinIdle(10);
    p.setLogAbandoned(true);
    p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    p.setJdbcInterceptors(
            "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"+
            "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
          datasource.setPoolProperties(p);
}

public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

    con = datasource.getConnection();
    return con;
}

public void close(Connection c) {
    con = c;
    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is my WEB-INF/web.xml (names changed to protect the guilty):

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
     <description>My Cool App</description>
    <resource-ref>
       <description>Cool Data Source</description>
       <res-ref-name>jdbc/postgres</res-ref-name>
       <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
       <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
       </resource-ref>
 </web-app>
```

Here is my context.xml stored in tomcat7/conf:

```
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->

    <Manager pathname="" />


    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->

<Resource name="jdbc/postgres" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/cooldb"
          username="cooluser" password="coolerpass" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
maxWait="-1"/>
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/postgres" name="jdbc/postgres" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>


</Context>
```

And last but not least here is a snippet from a JSP that calls into classes that connect to the database for various reasons and returns an ArrayList of data:

```
GenerateByFrequencyAndUnique gen = new GenerateByFrequencyAndUnique();
ArrayList<String> coolList = gen.generateMyListOfCoolStuff();
```

The code executes fine from Eclipse.. when it's deployed it just spins and in the catalina.out file the following exception is thrown about 10 times over 10 minutes before the jsp finally times out.

```
WARNING: Connection has been abandoned PooledConnection[org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@15f9c366]:java.lang.Exception
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getThreadDump(ConnectionPool.java:1072)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:789)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:187)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
at org.apache.jsp.generateSets_jsp._jspService(generateSets_jsp.java:139)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Another fun fact, I am running this on a Lenovo ThinkServer with Ubuntu.  I have verizon internet so to make the app viewable to the public I created a static IP address for the server, I then went into verizon router manager and opened a port forward so requests on port 80 that come into the verizon pooled connection will be forwarded to the server.. but the url in the browser shows the verizon url.

I have added the static IP and the verizon IPV6 address to the postgres config file and restarted the database but it didn't help.

Comment: You should create a database connection either from a servlet or a jsp file. Note that even if you have only jsp files, a servlet will be created internally. Of course, the servlet can then delegate a database connection  creation to whatever class you choose for the job.

Comment: Yes, I know that JSPs are transformed into servlets.  But I should seriously be able to create my connection in the jar that is in WEB-INF/lib .. I mean what if this were a pure angular instance that called web services.. you would have jars that had to connect to the database right?

Comment: Just create a servlet, create a connection there and dispatch your requests to whatever JSPs you want. It will make your development a lot easier. If the JNDI connection doesn't work (it should), try obtaining it through DriverManager. Web services still need a servlet (ServletContextListener will be the entry point in that case)

Comment: Web services still need a servlet (the class extending ServletContextListener will be the entry point in that case)

Comment: OK, I guess that beats another 2 days of downtime trying to get the new improved Tomcat to work

Comment: I have about 30 classes that expect the database connection to come from the manager so this is a lot of refactoring.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Put the business logic in the servlet and  have your servlet call your java classes (for particular jobs). Those classes can still call the connection manager (get the connection from there). Some refactoring may still be necessary though.

Comment: I refactored all of the DAOs .. and classes that call the DAOs to accept a connection in the constructor.. then I moved the connection code out of the dbm class and into the jsp.  So basically all of the code that you see above in the "DatabaseManager" class is now in the jsp.. and the constructor of GenerateByFrequencyAndUnique now requires a connection.  Still just sits and spins

Answer (score 0):

I can't post this as a comment, so I'll just write what I think you should do.

While you can write everything in a JSP file, it's messy and you'll help yourself by creating a servlet.

```
public class Your_servlet_class extends HttpServlet {


 public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

con = datasource.getConnection();
return con;
}

 //overriden 
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
        response) throws IOException, ServletException  {   
 //logic for http get requests

  Connection conn = getConnection();

  //now get some objects from the database (e.g in a List) and set a request   attribute
 request.setAttribute("someAttrName", list);//e.g. list of strings
  //someAttrName can now be used in your jsp page
  getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/SomePage.jsp").forward(request, response); 
}
 //overriden 
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
        response) throws IOException, ServletException  {   
 //logic for http post requests

  Connection conn = getConnection();
  //now change some objects in the database and return SomePage.jsp to the user

 getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/SomePage.jsp").forward(request, response);  
}
}
```

Comment: What is the difference?  A servlet is created from the JSP, it's NOT messy.. and I like it like that.. I don't think a servlet is going to fix this problem.. just doesn't make sense

Comment: No, I don't believe for one second that a servlet like this is required.. if it is that's just bloody stupid.. I wrote hundreds of JSPs 10 years ago that all connected to the database without issue.

Comment: It's not required and I already said that. Anyway, are you getting any exception?

Comment: =)  Sorry, I am getting a little frustrated .. yes, I have been able to capture this from the catalina.out file  Feb 12, 2016 6:10:13 PM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool abandon,   I have some print statements before and after the connection in the jsp.. I don't see them so I don't think a connection is ever established however.. the connection abandon exceptions are thrown in the catalina.out file several times before the jsp finally times out

Comment: Something I just thought of.. I am running this web server from my house through a verizon connection.  The URL to get to the app is a long convoluted pool address that verizon has.  I created a static ip on the web server then did a port forward so that requests to the pool would forward to the webserver.  I was thinking that I needed to put both the static ip and the verizon url in the pga conf file .. but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was caused by the Verizon router that I'm working through.  I set up port forwarding using the Verizon config tool for the router.. the problem is that I wasn't sending my database requests through that router.. I was attempting to go to 127.0.0.1, once I changed it to go through the Verizon URL and get forwarded to the database .. it works.

I did have to add a port forward rule in the router to allow requests to the database port to go to the database.

Comment: OK, this is really bizarre.  I added a port forward rule .. and had to change the url for the database to be the verizon URL and immediately I started seeing exceptions.. which is way better than just spinning.  I had to add entry to the postgres conf file and it took a few tries to get that set just right.. and then bam.. I'm back to abandoned connections and spinning.

Comment: If you're still having this issue, I suggest that  you post it in a new thread as it's a different problem. Hope it works out for you.

Comment: I did start a new thread in a different forum.  Really afraid to post here.. everybody down votes anything you ask or nobody replies .. seems like stackoverflow is dying

Comment: Yeah, you just have to hate this aspect of SO (it can be extremely unhelpful at times)